# How to check for empty values in Calendar object?

Tags: java, date

I am using calendar API to compare dates as so:

```
Date date = DateHelper.getDate(stringDate) This returns a date object
Calendar atPtmtCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
if(date != null){
    atPtmtCalendar.setTime(date)
}
```

The problem is that I am currently checking the variable date for null values rather than atPmtCalendar as so:

```
if(date != null){
     Boolean isBefore = atPtmtCalendar.before(otherCalendarDate)
}
```

Is there any way to check for null values by using atPtmtCalendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

No, you cannot use a possibly-null reference variable itself to see if it is null. You must check from outside the variable.

```
Objects                     // Handle utility class.
.requireNonNull( myDate )   // Throws exception if reference variable holds no reference, is null.
.toInstant()                // Convert from terrible legacy class `java.util.Date` to modern class `java.time.Instant`. 
.isBefore(                  // Compare one `Instant` object to another.
    Instant.now()           // Capture the current moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.
)                           // Returns true or false.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The `Date` & `Calendar` classes are terribly flawed. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `java.time.Instant`

When handed a `java.util.Date` object, immediately convert to its replacement, [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). Use the new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

For comparing, call any of the `Instant` methods: [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#isBefore(java.time.Instant)), `isAfter`.

## Null-check

As for checking for nulls… If your object reference such as `Calendar atPtmtCalendar` is null then you cannot call any methods with which to check for nulls. So your question “Is there any way to check for null values by using atPtmtCalendar?” makes no sense. So your null-check must be separate from your use of the possibly null variable.

I would prefer directly replacing your null check with a call to [`Objects.nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object)) for easier reading.

```
if( null != myVar ) { … }              // Not my favorite.
if( Objects.nonNull( myVar ) ) { … }   // Preferred by me.
```

If the variable should never be null, then throw an exception if it is indeed null. To do so, call [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)).  Optionally, you can pass text for the error message within the exception.

```
if( Objects.requireNonNull( myVar ) ) { … }
```

If null is a legitimate value in your particular scenario, then your called method should return an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html).

```
Optional< Date > date = whatever.getDate() ;
```

Your code can then use any of the several handy methods on `Optional` to handle the case of a missing payload.

## Example code

Putting all this together:

```
boolean isPastDate = 
    Objects
    .requireNonNull( myDate )
    .toInstant()
    .isBefore( 
        Instant.now() 
    ) 
;
```

Comment: Quoting you : "So your null-check must be separate from your use of the possible null variable" That means I am doing doing it in the correct if I continue using the calendar API

Comment: @Daniel Yes, `if(date != null) { … }` is technically correct. But generally best to reverse them, as a habit, to avoid a bug like this: `if( date = null )` which assigns a null rather than testing for a null. So I would advise `if( null != date )`. Even better, use `Objects.nonNull` as I advised in the Answer. As for `Calendar`,  there is *no* reason to ever use that troubled class. Move on to *java.time*.

Comment: The compiler will catch the error in `if( date = null )`, no risk having the value assigned.